# Windows Phone 7 DataServicesClient Request Headers Accept gzip

Tags: windows-phone-7, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that is utilizing the DataServicesClient to access a WCF DataService (ODATA) and I want to ask the service to compress the response.

I know if the Request Headers includes "Accept-Encoding" header with the value of "gzip" the WCF DS will compress the response.

Is there a way to add this header to the Request when using the DataServicesClient on WP7? The Request Headers collection appears to be readonly. What I would like to be able to do is the following (but the Headers property does not have an Add method in this context.)

```
void entities_SendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e) { e.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); }
```

- Michael

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify header collection with following code

```
private void OnSendingRequest(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.RequestHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like your other active question ;)

As mentioned on that question, it looks like the ODATA client has no way for you to modify the headers of a request before it is sent, though you could make a feature request.